# Get path to the External SdCard in android

Tags: android, storage

I want to get External SdCard path on devices if it available. by using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() I can get the path to the Internal Storage. So I used below class for detecting External storage.

```
public class ExternalStorage {
public static final String SD_CARD = "sdCard";
public static final String EXTERNAL_SD_CARD = "externalSdCard";

/**
 * @return True if the external storage is available. False otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isAvailable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static String getSdCardPath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
}

/**
 * @return True if the external storage is writable. False otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

/**
 * @return A map of all storage locations available
 */
public static Map<String, File> getAllStorageLocations() {
    Map<String, File> map = new HashMap<String, File>(10);

    List<String> mMounts = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    List<String> mVold = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    mMounts.add("/mnt/sdcard");
    mVold.add("/mnt/sdcard");

    try {
        File mountFile = new File("/proc/mounts");
        if(mountFile.exists()){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mountFile);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("/dev/block/vold/")) {
                    String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
                    String element = lineElements[1];

                    // don't add the default mount path
                    // it's already in the list.
                    if (!element.equals("/mnt/sdcard"))
                        mMounts.add(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        File voldFile = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");
        if(voldFile.exists()){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(voldFile);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
                    String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
                    String element = lineElements[2];

                    if (element.contains(":"))
                        element = element.substring(0, element.indexOf(":"));
                    if (!element.equals("/mnt/sdcard"))
                        mVold.add(element);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mMounts.size(); i++) {
        String mount = mMounts.get(i);
        if (!mVold.contains(mount))
            mMounts.remove(i--);
    }
    mVold.clear();

    List<String> mountHash = new ArrayList<String>(10);

    for(String mount : mMounts){
        File root = new File(mount);
        if (root.exists() && root.isDirectory() && root.canWrite()) {
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            String hash = "[";
            if(list!=null){
                for(File f : list){
                    hash += f.getName().hashCode()+":"+f.length()+", ";
                }
            }
            hash += "]";
            if(!mountHash.contains(hash)){
                String key = SD_CARD + "_" + map.size();
                if (map.size() == 0) {
                    key = SD_CARD;
                } else if (map.size() == 1) {
                    key = EXTERNAL_SD_CARD;
                }
                mountHash.add(hash);
                map.put(key, root);
            }
        }
    }

    mMounts.clear();

    if(map.isEmpty()){
        map.put(SD_CARD, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Example usage

```
    Map <String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage.getAllStorageLocations();
    File sdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.SD_CARD);
    File externalSdCard=externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);
```

on some device like Samsung Galaxy S3 it detects External SdCard correctly and return /storage/extSdCard for path to the External SdCard but on other devices like Sony Experia Z1 and Z2 it can't detect External Sdcard and give me the path to the Internal Storage. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Since you cannot access arbitrary locations on removable media on most Android devices (all running Android 4.4 or higher), you may wish to reconsider whatever it is that you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code in order to get sd card path

```
public class DiskHelper
{

    public static final int MODE_INTERNAL = 0;
    public static final int MODE_EXTERNAL = 1;
    public static final int MODE_EXTERNAL_SD = 2;
    private  StatFs statFs;
    protected String path;
    public DiskHelper(int mode)
    {
        try
        {
            if(mode == 0)
            {
                path = Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                statFs = new StatFs(path);
                statFs.restat(path);
            }
            else if(mode == 1)
            {
                path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                statFs = new StatFs(path);
                statFs.restat(path);
            }
            else
            {
                for(String str : getExternalMounts())
                {
                    path = str;
                    statFs = new StatFs(str);
                    statFs.restat(str);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            KLog.error(e);
        }
    }
    public String getPath()
    {
        return path;
    }
    public long getTotalMemory()
    {
        if(statFs == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        long total = ((long)statFs.getBlockCount() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize());
        return total;
    }

    public long getFreeMemory()
    {
        if(statFs == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        long free = ((long)statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize());
        return free;
    }

    public long getBusyMemory()
    {
        if(statFs == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        long   total  = getTotalMemory();
        long   free   = getFreeMemory();
        long   busy   = total - free;
        return busy;
    }


    public static HashSet<String> getExternalMounts()
    {

        final HashSet<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
        String reg = "(?i).*vold.*(vfat|ntfs|exfat|fat32|ext3|ext4).*rw.*";
        String s = "";
        try
        {
            final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            process.waitFor();
            final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while(is.read(buffer) != -1)
            {
                s = s + new String(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            KLog.error(e);
        }
        final String[] lines = s.split("\n");
        for (String line : lines)
        {
            if(!line.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("asec"))
            {
                if(line.matches(reg))
                {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    for(String part : parts)
                    {
                        if(part.startsWith("/"))
                        {
                            if(!part.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("vold"))
                            {
                                out.add(part);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
    private static final long  MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;
    public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si)
    {
        if(true)
        {
            long ret =  bytes / MEGABYTE;
            return ret + " MB";
        }
        int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
        if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
        int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
        String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
        return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
    }


}
```

Then

```
final DiskHelper sdDiskHelper = new DiskHelper(DiskHelper.MODE_EXTERNAL_SD);
path = sdDiskHelper.getPath();
```

You can customize this class.

Comment: I used your class but I got permission denied Exception on LG G3 device. Android don't allow me to create Directory on External Storage.

Answer (score 0):

String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");

File externalsdpath = new File(secStore);

This will get the path of external sd secondary storage.